# How do I copy files from my RPi to my current computer

Tags: bash, ssh, raspberry-pi

I want to transfer all of my files from my RPi, which I have gotten into via ssh, and I want to copy all the files from the computer to my current one because I am planning to put Arch GNU onto my RPi. But I have some important files on that computer and I do not want to buy another SD card. So how can I use SCP to copy all files from my RPi to my current computer?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the SD card from RPi, put it in a card reader and connect the reader to the PC. You'll need Linux or an ext filesystem driver to access Linux partition.

Alternatively, since you have SSH access, you could connect to RPi with SFTP protocol and pull your files. SCP is also an option. You can use FileZilla or WinSCP to do that.

Answer (score -2):

you could use ssh to ftp or sftp, if ssh is enabled open up a terminal from your computer with the IP of the pi and run ssh host@ip_of_machine. Use the sftp or ftp(secure file transfer protocol and file transfer protocol); Sftp or ftp -h or --help for flags and parameters on both, in edition you might have to run with sudo command so it'd be sudo ssh host@ip_of_machine where host is the name in front of @ in your terminal line.